# I'd need a gigantic bitmapped font

Tags: linux, x11, opensuse, fonts

My laptop display has ~180 dpi, and it's fine. But.
Sometimes I need to run old X apps (now, it's `osd_cat`) that do not support scalable fonts, and what is displayed is miserably small.

---

The largest bitmapped font I've on Suse Tumbleweed is

```
-etl-fixed-medium-r-normal--40-400-72-72-c-200-iso8859-1
```

and while it's readable, I'd like to find and install something even larger.

Do you know of an available bitmapped font, possibly mono spaced, with a pixel height larger than 40 pixels?

---

PS As much as possible, I'd like to be addressed to a single BDF file, that I can drop into a system directory and run `mkfontdir`.

Answer (score 15):

You can scale up a bdf font with [bdfresize](https://github.com/ntwk/bdfresize).

Or you can retrieve a font from the X11 server, converting it into bdf, with [getbdf](https://github.com/strickyak/X11-getbdf).

Answer (score 0):

I apparently forgot that `X` can convert {O,T}TF fonts to bitmaps on the fly, provided that your distribution a) places a convenient set of `fonts.dir`, `fonts.scale` and optionally `fonts.alias` in the font directory and b) adds the font directory to X's font path.

E.g., Suse Tumbleweed, an 80 pixel high font can be requested as

```
-*-noto sans extrabold-*-r-*-*-80-*-0-0-*-*-*-*
```

In my use case it may be a little onerous because i repeatedly call `osd_cat`, but maybe the X server caches the bitmapped font, and even if it doesn't, I have too many cores waiting idle and too much memory available while I make a presentation...